# Safari default keychain to store the autofill info

Tags: macos, safari, keychain

I'm testing the autofill feature of Safari. When I add the login and password for a site, Safari stores the information in the "Local Items" Keychain. My question is if I can change this default keychain to another one, for example mykeychain. I want to use a password protected keychain only to autofill data.

Is this change possible on macOS?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit it :)